# Use SSL with Dart and Managed VM's

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, dart

I wish to know how I can use a secure connection (https) with Dart and Managed VM's on localhost and when it's deployed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an application is *deployed* using `gcloud preview app deploy` the default is that the App Engine application will be served on both HTTP and HTTPS. If you have an application on

> http://project.appspot.com

you can access it using HTTPS on

> https://project.appspot.com

If not accessing the default version the URL are:

> http://version.project.appspot.com

and HTTPS on

> https://version-dot-project.appspot.com

Note the first . changing to -dot-.

You can specify the following int the app.yaml to *only* serve the application over HTTPS:

```
- url: /.*
  script: dummy
  secure: always
```

This will also redirect from HTTP to HTTPS, but unfortunately not do the rewrite from . to -dot- if not using the default version.

For *local* development using `gcloud preview app run` it is *not* possible to use HTTPS. The following quote is from the App Engine documentation:

> The development web server does not support HTTPS connections. It
>   ignores the secure parameter, so paths intended for use with HTTPS can
>   be tested using regular HTTP connections to the development web
>   server.

See https://github.com/dart-lang/appengine/issues/16 and https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Secure_URLs.